# How to execute a system command that prints in color while capturing output, but can also be cancelled in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminal

Ruby has a lot of ways to run system commands, be it with system(), or exec(), or backticks, etc.

However, I've been finding that only system and exec (as far as I know) are able to print the colored output of some of my commands while also providing a PID which allows me to cancel the command.

Is there any other way to run system commands from a Ruby command-line script such that I am able to meet the following requirements?

1. See the colored output (helps with organization)
2. Capture output to a variable
3. Get a PID so I can cancel execution if I need to (I already have the code for this, I just need the PID)

Comment: Perhaps Process.spawn and passing in IO redirection? I've seen Foreman do this for prepending the server name for each pid to all of the output logs during log aggregation https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/master/lib/foreman/process.rb#L54

Comment: As for colored output, Ruby doesn't filter the output at all. If the output includes ANSI color codes and you capture the output, you'll get them.

Comment: You should be able to cancel a script with `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with it for a while, I found that IO.popen returns an object that contains the pid, and can also be used to print all captured output. It also doesn't interfere with the ANSI output of system commands called from within Ruby. My code looks something like this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def shutdown()
    `kill #{$pid}`
end

["INT", "KILL", "TERM"].each { |_sig| Signal.trap(_sig) { shutdown() }     }

process = IO.popen("ls --color ~; ping -c 10 www.google.com")
$pid = process.pid
process.each { |_line| puts _line }
```

I can thus cancel the ls and ping commands without cancelling my Ruby code with a control-C from terminal, and also manipulate the lines before printing them if I want to.

Answer (score -1):

Another similar solution is to use `$stdout` global as in:

`` $stdout.puts `ls --color ~; ping -c 10 www.google.com` ``

Comment: This does not work (colorization is lost) in my environment : Mac OSX el capitan, bash, iTerm2 and Ruby 2.0.0.